# Using FractionallySizedBox in a Row

Tags: flutter

I want to have a widget of arbitrary width that contains a row of three widgets sized relatively to its parent.

`FractionallySizedBox` sounds like the right tool for the job, so I tried it like this:

```
Container(height: 24.0, color: Colors.black, child:
  Row(children: [
    FractionallySizedBox(heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.25,
                         child: Container(color: Colors.orange)),
    FractionallySizedBox(heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.15,
                         child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
    FractionallySizedBox(heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.05,
                         child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
  ]
)
```

But I'm getting an error

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

This happens even when I set some width on the enclosing container.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You should report this as a bug, it should be able to function inside a Row or Column.

Comment: This should work when FractionallySizedBox is wrapped in a Flexible. Reported this a bug.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44733

Answer (score 31):

As explained in the "FractionallySizedBox (Flutter Widget of the Week)" video by the Flutter team, the FractionallySizedBox needs to be wrapped in Flexible widget, "so it plays well with a row or a column".

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0

This should be the solution to the original question, formatted below:

```
Container(
    height: 24.0, 
    color: Colors.black, 
    child: Row(
        children: [
            Flexible(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.25,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
                ),
            ),
            Flexible(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.15,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
            ),
            Flexible(
                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.05,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.blue)
                ),
            ),
        ]
    )
)
```

I have also worked on something similar and was looking for a solution to the problem, this is my code for representing data levels:

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
              height: 6,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125)),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
              height: 6,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125)),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
              height: 6,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125)),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
              height: 6,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125)),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
              height: 6,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(125)),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    ],
),
```

Resulting in:
[evenly spaced bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx6QT.png)

Answer (score 16):

You can't use `FractionallySizedBox` in Row or Column directly. You can split as percent Row and Column use flex parameter of Expand widget like below.

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 6, // 60% of space => (6/(6 + 4))
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 4, // 40% of space
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Why would they say it plays well with a row or column around second 45: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG&index=53&t=0s

Comment: @SoufianeGhzal You can wrap FractionallySizedBox with Expanded or Flexible widget, could not use directly. Already They wrap it with Flexible in the video.

Comment: Yes got it, I just find it confusing because the way they say it you think it's possible to use a it directly to size in a row or column. At least it's what I understood at first.

Answer (score 5):

FractionallySizedBox seems to only work outside of Row, Column, and Wrap widgets. I would recommend this approach instead:

```
class FractionalPositioningQuestion extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Replace with the size your parent widget is.
    final pWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: pWidth * 0.25,
        color: Colors.orange,
      ),
      Container(
        width: pWidth * 0.15,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      Container(
        width: pWidth * 0.05,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ],
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Depending on what you want
    );
  }
}
```

You still need to find a way to obtain the arbitrary width of the parent widget though.

Hope this helps a little at least :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if your row consumes the entire width of the display. If you have padding around the row, of the row is a component, you'll be sad.

Answer (score 3):

`FractionallySizedBox` refused to work within Rows.
Much easier to use the flex field of Expanded.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

myRow() => Row(children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 8,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 2,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ]);

content() => Column(children: [
      Text(" ----Start ----"),
      myRow(),
      Text(" ----End ----"),
    ]);

void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Playground',
      home: Material(
          child: SafeArea(child: Container(width: 80, child: content()))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FractionallySizedBox doesn't work as expected in rows and columns, *even wrapped in a Flexible widget.*

tldr: It seems like the heightFactor (for columns) is applied not to the box itself, but to the column overall. This is a neat effect, but not what is expected

Details:

I made a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0d97a4202a0cd8838aa25713f1c19c13&null_safety=true) that lets you see it.

- OrangeBoxes have heighFactor=0.5 (you can change it in the code)
- BlueBoxes are fixed at 20px by 20px.

#### Problem1

Expected Behavior: Two OrangeBoxes take up the whole screen. Half each.
Actual Behavior: Two OrangeBoxes each take up 1/4.

#### Problem2

Expected Behavior: One OrangeBox takes up half the screen. Adding BlueBoxes doesn't make the Orange Box smaller.
Actual Behavior: Adding BlueBoxes makes the OrangeBox smaller. So that the *whole column* takes up half the screen. Then, if many Blue Boxes added, the whole column eventually grows.

### Photos

[image: One Box by itself, works! But columns usually have more than one item]

[image: Two boxes. Expect each is half. Actual is overall column is half.]

[image: One big box and several smaller. The smaller ones make the 0.5 Orange box smaller.]

I also tested this on Android, and I get the same rendering behavior from a quick-and-dirty check.

#### Extra Notes

The gist is here if someday the dartpad link breaks
https://gist.github.com/chonghorizons/0d97a4202a0cd8838aa25713f1c19c13