# I want to place a widget whose size is specified using FractionallySizedBox as a child widget of Row, but an error occurs

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to use the code below to place a widget whose size is specified using FractionallySizedBox as a child widget of Row, but an error occurs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 50,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                BottomWidget(),
                BottomWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class BottomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.25,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error code:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the horizontal direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
```

The solution to this error is to wrap it by specifying a value in the height property of something like SizedBox instead of `FractionallySizedBox`. But I want to specify the size with `FractionallySizedBox`.

But I can't resolve this error. How can I use `FractionallySizedBox` to place a widget with a specified size as a child widget of a Row?

https://dartpad.dev/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using FractionallySizedBox in a Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242651/using-fractionallysizedbox-in-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `Row`'s width is unbounded, because of you display a `Row` in a `Stack`, you need to add a width constraint to the `Row`

```
Positioned(
  top: 50,
  child: SizedBox(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        BottomWidget(),
        BottomWidget(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: you can also use `left,right` from  `Positioned`